# Release notes details in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

What is the best way if I want to keep my Release notes or any change sets details in Artifactory for each build that was created.

I  am using Artifactory OSS version with Jenkins plug-in. I deploy my builds from Jenkins , Is there a way to store my release notes details from TFS in Artifactory ?

There is a tab in Artifactory "Release History" , Is the relevant tab to put my Release Notes.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Can anybody response or please give a lead how to tackle such request. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am researching the exact same thing right now and I think I've found the answer.
Unfortunately I am not able to speak from experience yet, because I will start using Artifactory in a month or so.

Actual answer: I think you need to use [Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Properties) functionality of Artifactory.

There are two YouTube videos directly from JFrog regarding properties:
[Artifactory 3.X - Using property-sets to tag and search for artifacts in Artifactory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUs3XQL_j8g) (yes, I know it's from 2009)
[Artifactory 4.0 Jenkins Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxtQThl8B-8) - the segments:

- 08:10 - Artifactory Build Info JSON
- 10:01 - Build Related Properties
- 10:36 - Properties Search

Comment: @drorb - I see that you work for JFrog - can you help validate if my answer is what the original poster is looking for?